# CodegenCFunctions.tpl -> algStmtAssignWithRhsExpStr: Unhandled lhs expression error

Tags: openmodelica

I have an external Fortran function which returns a 20 dimensional vector and accepts a series of inputs. These outputs are mostly used in order to store the solution in Modelica (for plotting purposes) but a small subset of them are used in a control loop. Whenever I use more than one of these outputs in the feedback loop I get the following errors:

`Internal error BackendDAEUtil.getAdjacencyMatrixEnhancedScalar failed`

`Translation Error` `[CodegenCFunctions.tpl: 2640:11-2640:11]: algStmtAssignWithRhsExpStr: Unhandled lhs expression. {$...}`

and the following:
`Internal Error .../lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/omc/libOpenModelicaCompile.so: (null) failed`

What is your suggestion for solving this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: I opened an issue about this here: https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/7743 please add additional info there (what version of OM you are using, etc). Also, if you can provide an example would make it much easier for us to debug this.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have added a replication of the problem in the issue you have opened.